# Task List desktop app using Visual Studio 2015

Tags: sharepoint-online, visual-studio-2013

Is it possible to develop in Visual Studio 2015 a Desktop App that will retrieve Tasks from multiple task lists in a Office 365 Collection and display them based on the currently logging in user?

Does anyone have samples or guides to create this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can access lists programmatically using the Client Library:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179912.aspx#BasicOps_SPListTasks

or for JavaScript:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163201.aspx#BasicOps_SPListItemTasks

Identifying logged in users:
http://blog.furuknap.net/find-number-of-users-currently-logged-on-to-a-sharepoint-site

I've given up on SharePoint Online, myself, as MS has continued to lock-down and restrict access to everything that I found to be of any use, but I'm pretty sure you are still able to read Lists etc.